# How to restore a particular app's data from Google Drive backup?

Tags: restore, google-drive, realme

I have hard reset my android phone and I have restored it from a backup in Google drive which was taken 2 days ago. Some of the apps are installed.

There are however some system apps whose data is not restored.

I can see from the Backup that there was about 750KB of data for system app which can be restored. But it is not restored.

The app has no option to restore data from Google drive backup  also.

I have also tried Google Takeout (for Google Drive) bit it did not give me the Android backup data.

**Question**

How to restore a particular app's data from Google drive?

Also, is it possible to download the Google drive backup data on PC or to some storage and try to extract it?

Can I restore it on any emulator like Genymotion to get the data?

Answer (score 1):

The applications that was not restored does not allow backup (`android:allowBackup="false"`). Which mean that your backup will not contain these applications even after restoring in another device.

You can check that by following these steps:

- Install one of the concerned Apps in your new device
- Enable USB Debugging
- Run this command (using ADB):

```
adb shell dumpsys package concerend.app.package | grep flags
```

Where `concerend.app.package` is the package name of the installed App.

If ALLOW_BACKUP exist in the command's result then probably the application can be backed up. Else, the application cannot be backed up and it will explain why it was not restored.